# Lined drawn at stage appear on the next and previous frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using code for matching objects by drawing lines, the code working well but the lines drawn appear on next and previous frames when pressing next and previous buttons

`

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;

var p1:Point = new Point();
var p2:Point = new Point();


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setP1);
function setP1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    p1.x=mouseX;
    p1.y=mouseY;
    
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
    s=new Shape();
    stage.addChild(s);
}

var s:Shape;

function draw(e:MouseEvent):void {
    s.graphics.clear();
    s.graphics.lineStyle(4,0xff0000, 1);
    s.graphics.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    p2.setTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    s.graphics.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y)
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, end);
function end(e:MouseEvent):void {
    
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
    if (MC_1.hitTestPoint(p1.x,p1.y) && MC_1_1.hitTestPoint(p2.x, p2.y))
        
    {
        
    }
    else {
        s.graphics.clear();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: It is expected result. The drawing is not bound to the current frame, it is bound to the whole object. If you want the drawings to disappear on moving to another frame, call **graphics.clear();** with the **gotoAndStop/gotoAndPlay/nextFrame/prevFrame**.

Comment: I add **graphics.clear();** but the same result the line still appear and the following error appear TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Unit5_fla::MainTimeline/end()

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I put a bit of thought into it and found out that you

- attach the **Shape**s directly to the **stage** rather then to the current context
- don't bother to keep track of them

I enhanced your script a bit so that it keeps everything you create there (I don't know if you are working with multiple lines, so just in case), and there's a **cleanUp()** method you should call to undo literally everything the rest of the script does.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;

var P1:Point = new Point;
var P2:Point = new Point;

// A list of Shapes that will probably stockpile here.
var Slist:Array = new Array;

// The Shape to work with.
var S:Shape;

// Subscribe to the event to start drawing.
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Subscribe to the relevant events.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
    
    // Create an object for drawing.
    S = new Shape;
    Slist.push(S);
    stage.addChild(s);
    
    P1.x = S.mouseX;
    P1.y = S.mouseY;
    
    // First draw.
    onDraw(e);
}

// Draw the line every time the mouse moves.
function onDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Memorize the endpoint coordinates.
    P2.x = S.mouseX;
    P2.y = S.mouseY;
    
    // Drawing routine.
    S.graphics.clear();
    S.graphics.lineStyle(4,0xff0000, 1);
    S.graphics.moveTo(P1.x, P1.y);
    S.graphics.lineTo(P2.x, P2.y);
}

// End the drawing process.
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onDraw);
    
    // Last draw,
    onDraw(e);
    
    // Convert Points to stage coordinates. I know they are identical in
    // the present setup, but it is not the reason to ignore the operation.
    var GP1:Point = S.localToGlobal(P1);
    var GP2:Point = S.localToGlobal(P2);
    
    var aHit1:Boolean = MC_1.hitTestPoint(GP1.x, GP1.y);
    var aHit2:Boolean = MC_1_1.hitTestPoint(GP2.x, GP2.y);

    if (aHit1 && aHit2)
    {
        // Whatever you need to do here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Erase the unneeded Shape.
        stage.removeChild(S);
        
        var anIndex:int = Slist.indexOf(S);
        if (anIndex > -1) Slist.splice(anIndex, 1);
        
        S.graphics.clear();
        S = null;
    }
}

// Call this at the same time you go to another frame.
function cleanUp():void
{
    // Clean the stockpiled objects if any.
    while (Slist.length)
    {
        S = Slist.pop();
        if (!S) continue;
        if (!(S is Shape)) continue;
        
        S.graphics.clear();
        
        if (!S.parent) continue;
        S.parent.removeChild(S);
    }
    
    // Destroy all the relevant objects.
    S = null;
    P1 = null;
    P2 = null;
    Slist = null;
    
    // Finally, unsubscribe from DOWN handler (and the rest just in case).
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);        
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onDraw);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Organis it works!, I only create mc name it (canvas) and substitute stage by it, (canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent..........)